# Como mandar alocar mais memória na execução do app?

Tags: java, android, mobile, thread

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo [android](/questions/tagged/android)

Atualmente, quando executo o APP, ele inicia reservando 36,62 MB de memória.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Gostaria que ele iniciasse a cima de 50,00 MB ou, quando chegasse no seu limite, acrescentasse mais memória.

---

Existe alguma forma de definir a memória inicial da Thread principal?

Sei que quando declaramos uma nova Thread, conseguimos alocar um tamanho de pilha para ela como por exemplo:

```
//https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html
//long stackSize define o tamanho da stack . . .
Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target, String name, long stackSize)
```

Mas na Thread principal não sei como fazer

---

Alguém saberia me orientar referente a isso?

Comment: Por padrão da JVM ele vai liberando memoria aos poucos, de acordo com a demanda, e claro, tem um limite, para aplicações que usam mais memorias podem ser definido no manifest o aumento dela conforme a resposta que @Rogers Marques postou, vc pode ver mais detalhes do erro de consumo de memoria nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012006/android-outofmemoryerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Manifest.xml de sua aplicação adicione

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

isso fará com que ele use mais memória que o padrão definido, atenção sua aplicação não vai rodar gastando mais memória, mas vamos supor que antes sua aplicação por ter muitos elementos acabe estourando a memória padrão que cada app pode consumir, com essa linha ele não impõe limite de consumo de memória ram.

Veja mais:

> Se os processos da sua aplicação devem ser criados com uma
>   grande pilha Dalvik. Isso se aplica a todos os processos criados para
>   o aplicativo. Aplica-se apenas ao primeiro aplicativo carregado em um
>   processo; se você estiver usando uma ID de usuário compartilhada para
>   permitir que vários aplicativos usem um processo, todos eles devem
>   usar esta opção de forma consistente ou terão resultados
>   imprevisíveis. A maioria dos aplicativos não deve precisar disso e
>   deve concentrar-se em reduzir o uso geral da memória para melhorar o
>   desempenho. Habilitar isso também não garante um aumento fixo na
>   memória disponível, porque alguns dispositivos são limitados pela
>   memória total disponível.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html